# Error "VirtualMachineError: revert: Fallback not allowed" when executing "weth.balanceOf(flashloan)"

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, brownie

I am trying to run the "run_flash_loan_v2.py" script from https://github.com/brownie-mix/aave-flashloan-mix code.

I am trying to run it on Mumbai network. The brownie-config was changed for the Mumbai network. The contracts are:

```
polygon-test:
    aave_lending_pool_v2: "0x178113104fEcbcD7fF8669a0150721e231F0FD4B"
    weth: "0xee9eE614Ad26963bEc1Bec0D2c92879ae1F209fA"
```

I have got WMATIC and deployed the contract using the command "brownie run scripts/deployment_v2.py --network polygon-test"

However when I run "brownie run scripts/run_flash_loan_v2.py --network polygon-test", I get the following error:

```
Getting Flashloan contract...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/run_flash_loan_v2.py", line 16, in main
    if weth.balanceOf(flashloan) < MINIMUM_FLASHLOAN_WETH_BALANCE:
  File "brownie/network/multicall.py", line 115, in _proxy_call
    result = ContractCall.__call__(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1751, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, block_identifier=block_identifier, override=override)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1542, in call
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
VirtualMachineError: revert: Fallback not allowed
```

I have read that the command `if weth.balanceOf(flashloan) < MINIMUM_FLASHLOAN_WETH_BALANCE` is understood by Mumbai virtual machine as for checking WMATIC (or at least it is supposed to be understood like that).

I am using the wallet 0x7cc6FA028dffa310445af40C3abEea61F8534d97... which has the funds.

Hope someone knows what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Double check WETH (WMATIC) address. It must be WETH, not WETH gateway. You can see contract addresses in AAVE [documentation](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market).

Comment: IDK why someone marked my answer is not useful. No problem, let me comment. You run balanceOf on WETH gateway, that is why you get the error. You need to run this method on WETH token contract, not gateway.

In the brownie-config you specified WETH gateway, try to replace it with token contract you are using (WETH or WMATIC). Their addresses specified in my link above.